# Prove such an entire analytic function doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there is no entire analytical function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $$f(z)=\exp\left( \frac{2\pi i}{z}\right)$$

on $|z|=1.$

Could any one give me some insight on this? Thank you!

Comment: The key to these types of problems is to use the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)

Comment: You should retype your question from the image  if you would like assistance. Also, we generally want to know what you tried and where you got stuck

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference.

Comment: That's so sweet of you, I actually didn't know how to type a question like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Let $g:U=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be defined by $g(z)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{z}\right)$. It is clear that $g$ is holomorphic in $U$.

Since $f-g\equiv 0$ in the unit circle, the set $\{z\in U:f(z)-g(z)=0\}$ has a limit point in $U$ (it has uncountably many). Furthermore, since $U$ is connected, it follows that $f=g$ in $U$ by the identity principle. But then $f$ cannot be entire, for it is unbounded in arbitrarily small neighborhoods of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

This may be wrong, but why can't we just consider the contour integral of f(z) dz on the circle |z|=1? If f is analytic by Cauchy's theorem this should be 0 but clearly (expanding exp as infinite series) we see integral |z|=1 exp(2 pi i/z) dz is non-zero!

EDIT

Let a be a non-zero constant. Then we know e^(a/z) = 1 + a/z +a^2/2z^2+... as we are integrating around unit circle all the terms except a/z vanish under integration dz leaving Integral(e^(a/z))= 2 pi i a where the integral is around the unit circle. This is clearly non-zero.

Comment: That is a perfectly valid line of attack.  But you should edit your answer to include the details of how to deduce that the infinite series converges to a non-zero value, since I don't think that is particularly clear.

Comment: @Erick Wong Thank u very much Erick, I have edited it, is it sensible now? Just wanted to check the method was valid (and is maybe a little more direct than using the identity theorem?)

Comment: It seems pretty reasonable to me, thank you for editing.  I guess how direct it is depends a bit on the order of presentation of topics in a particular curriculum :).  In some texts power series would be treated quite early, including justification of term-by-term integration.